# How acceptable is "fully fledged" as opposed to "full-fledged"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

As a native speaker of English, I had never heard the "fully" version until recently. Now I seem to hear it a lot, but only from non-native speakers. Are the two equally acceptable in semi-formal writing?

Comment: Personally, I hear "fully fledged" and I think of something with with all of its feathers...

Comment: @SeanDuggan that is exactly what it means. It's a metaphor.

Answer (score 14):

Also as a native speaker, I've never heard "full fledged", only "fully fledged" so I suppose we're even.

"Full" as an adverb feels a bit archaic, only generally used in stock phrases such as "full in the face", "know full well" -- although of course "full fledged" could be one such phrase.

[NGram says](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fully%20fledged,%20full%20fledged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that "full fledged" became more popular than "fully fledged" between ~1910 and 1940,  but that before then and overwhelmingly since, "fully" is more common.
[image: Ngram graph]

Additionally, dictionary.com says that the adverb "full" means "exactly or directly" and "fully" means "completely or entirely". By those definitions, "fully fledged" is the only phrase of the two that really makes sense.

Comment: Wale dogies, I guess I've been crazier'n a coon dog in July. Or maybe it's a regionalism.

Comment: Must confess this comes as a surprise. Slim, did you believe it?

Comment: @Kris It's what I expected to see. "Full fledged" sounds archaic to me, as I said. "Fully" is the modern adverb.

Comment: @slim [The OED respectively disagrees with you.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71381) N–Grams is never an acceptable substitute for actual scholarship. Notice that it admits **full-fledged, half-fledged,** and **new-fledged**. People who say *fully-fledged* as adjective probably say *orientated*, too, which just sounds silly. Normal usage is “The young chick was at last fully fledged” but “That’s a full-fledged idea.”  Note the difference.

Comment: @tchrist Do you mean "respectfully disagrees"? Anyway, it's paywalled. Can you summarise? Or link to one of the lesser, free dictionaries?

Comment: @slim Yes, I meant *respectfully*.   One need no more say a fully-fledged idea than a newly-born babe. It’s a new-born babe and a full-fledged idea.  This ‘modern’ hangup with -ly forms is as excessive as -ical forms for -ic forms, or -tated forms for -ed forms. It’s all just a bunch of extraneous and unnecessarily wordy additions to perfectly adequate terms. I would not analyse the lengthier forms so much as ‘modern’ as you do, but rather as um, ‘logorrhoeic’. :)

Comment: @tchrist Hmm, when OED contradicts actual usage (and the margins are significant) I tend to think the "actual scholarship" is at fault.

Comment: @slim  I have provided you with contrastive examples that rightly and distintively call for ‘fully fledged’ and for ‘full-fledged’. To apply ‘fully-fledged’ across the board is no more defensible than to pretend that ‘newly-born’ is more modern than ‘new-born’. Indeed, it borders on pretense. It’s logorrhoeic mumblespeak, and not to be encouraged. Down that road lies Newlyfoundland, and similar lies.

Comment: I think we may be onto something with the hyphens. I think it's "fully fledged" but "full-fledged". Not "fully-fledged" or "full fledged". In speech, this manifests itself in emphasis. "**Full**-fledged". "Fully **fledged**". Unfortunately ngrams doesn't handle hyphens. And I think it's "newborn" as a single word. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=newborn%2Cnew+born%2C+newly+born&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @slim Ya, I was thinking likewise, but there was a little surprise in store. Even though google replies a large no. of entries for "full-fledged", but unfortunately ngram doesnt show any! Any idea, why so?

Comment: @karthik NGrams apparently doesn't handle hyphens well. Pity.

Comment: Precisely because of the hyphen, this is a case where nGrams presents a false, or at least skewed, view. Clearly, "fully fledged" occurs more frequently than the hyphen-less "full fledged", but that's because the latter is incorrect without a hyphen. All this graph is showing is that a correct phrase occurs more frequently than an incorrect one, which is hardly astounding news.

Comment: @tchrist There is no reason that [adverb + past participle] should only be used predicatively, substituting instead [adjective + participle] for attributive uses. The hyphen is conventional for this particular word, but it is unnecessary: a _fully fledged_ something is no different from a something that is _fully fledged_. Would you also say that a plan that is fully developed is a full-developed plan by necessity, and not a fully developed one? _Full-fledged_ sounds bizarre to me simply because it’s not the form I’m used to; doesn’t make it any more or less logical or logorrhoeic.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the OED entry linked says "This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1896)." Usage has probably changed in the past 124 years.

Answer (score 6):

I feel the picture gets more clear if you see this graph: This is for American English only.

[image]

whereas, for British English:

[image]

I am more comfortable with full-fledged, as that is what I have heard more. Also, there is a large number of people who sill use it quite frequently. Also, as the graph shows in more than one time of the past both have been used with almost same popularity in American English, e.g. 1960, 1900, 1870 (approx.), 1880, 1845 (approx.) etc., though as Slim has shown, there was a gap overall, the major contribution being from the British English towards fully-fledged.

Though, this doesn't make things even, but at least shows the difference in bias, in two variants of the language.

Comment: nGrams are context-agnostic -- so draw no early conclusions from them.

Comment: I would agree, if the bias were not so far apart. Plz notice the red curve in one is barely grazing the horizontal, and in another has risen and fallen. So, clearly, it was largely popular in American English usage, and rarely used in British English. Also, I must point out both the terms are used in similar contexts. So, the agnosticism does not create problems.

Comment: This fits my own experience as an educated British English native speaker. I had never heard "full-fledged" (or perhaps if I ever heard it in US speech, corrected it subconsciously). It shows that even those of us with the most reputation should be careful not to be too dogmatic.

Answer (score -1):

as a non-native speaker, I would be tempted to say:

- full-fledged (the subject "flesh" is complete)
- fully-fletched (the arrow has all necessary feathers)

My 2 cents !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).