# What's the opposite of "prototype product"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms

From an Information Technology perspective, what's the opposite of Proof of Concept (prototype)?

I'm looking for a better word which means "full-fledged version".

Comment: I wouldn't really call that an "opposite", though.

Comment: I agree - the opposite would be no product at all.

Comment: See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58022/2085).

Comment: Opposite of "proof of concept"? *"Disproof of concept"?* While I've never heard this used, it is clearly needed for certain pieces of vaporware.

Comment: Interesting that you used "full-fledged".     It seems quite apt. http://i.word.com/idictionary/full-fledged   It comes from "fledge" which literally means (for a bird) to become ready to fly on its own.  http://i.word.com/idictionary/fledge

Comment: In my experience (computers/programming) it would usually be a "*released* product".  (Though I often accuse a product of having "escaped" vs being "released".)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The opposite of a prototype — or a blueprint, or a sketch, or a mock-up, or a model — is a *finished product* or *production version*.

Comment: Any other terms? I think he's looking for a synonym of "production version", like how "prototype" is the synonym for "alpha version".

Comment: Just *production*. 'Is this production or just a prototype?' - The opposite of prototype is *a wall hanger*, as w/e it is, it's on its way out of use as opposed to coming into it.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a *turnkey project*. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnkey) explains this as:

> a type of project that is constructed so that it could be sold to any buyer as a completed product.

But with *full-fledged version* they would certainly know what you are referring to.

Comment: Like the word "TurnKey", But I doubt if people would really understand it. Glad to learn a new word today. Thanks.

Comment: @vonjd, "turnkey" is the wrong term. Full fledged products can be both turnkey and non-turnkeys, they are not related in any way.

Comment: "Turnkey" refers to how the product is delivered -- whether the supplier or the customer is responsible for installation and setup.

Answer (score -1):

It can be called as Beta Version or Feature Complete.

(Reference: see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle).)

Comment: Beta still has the connotation of a product that is known to be not quite ready. Technically, you're right; a beta version should have everything the customer has asked for and behave as they said it should; the beta test period is where you discover anything that differs between "what they asked for" and "what they need/want". It is common knowledge, however, that those two rarely meet on the first try.