# What is the word for something that is based on a prototype?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, analogy, programming

If two objects (or "types") have the relationship where one is the prototype of the other, then the other is the **__** of the prototype.

In this sentence, from the context of the prototype:

> This will not be true for versions that are based on this version.

I want to replace the words "versions that are based on this version" with one word.  For example, in the context of one of those future versions, I could say "This was not true for prototypes."

Examples of the kind of *prototypal* relationship I am looking for:

> Chair is to Stool
>   Protoplast is to Chloroplast

Examples of the kind of *word* relationship I am looking for:

> Archetype is to Ectype
>   Supertype is to Subtype
>
> Prototype is to **_**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the examples you're provided all seem to be superset/subset pairs, whereas the word you're requesting would not be either a superset of subset of "prototype."  If you do want your requested word to be a superset or subset, could you clarify which one?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on context, you could call a non-prototype a *[production model](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/production_model)*, although it seems that this term refers [primarily](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/production) to vehicles. You might also replace *model* with *unit* or *version*. [This Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=production%20model,production%20unit,production%20version&year_start=1850&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) seems to indicate that *production unit*  is the most popular of those three options.

If you are dealing with software, you could call it *shipping a 1.0 product* or merely a *1.0*. *Release version* is another candidate. And if there are multiple prototypes, they are sometimes referred to as *[pre-alphas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pre-alpha_version)*, *[alphas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alpha_version)* or *[betas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beta_version)* in the programming community. A prototype that is almost ready for distribution is often called a *[release candidate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/release_candidate)*.

**Added**: see [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106565/whats-the-opposite-of-proof-of-concept) dealing with the opposite of a *proof of concept*.

Comment: Thank you. All good thoughts. I think the relationship I'm trying to describe is more akin to "Animal is to Mammal" as "Prototype is to _____".  Maybe the problem is the word `prototype`? Still seems strange if there isn't a counterpart that fits this description.

Comment: This is interesting because in the context of software engineering, I would consider the finished product to be more of an archetype than an intermediate type that has both a prototype and an archetype.  In other words, a software product is never truly a finished product.  It is just a product, which has both predecessors and successors, at least conceptually.  And "production unit" describes a particular "type" or "model" that is suitable for productization, rather than the relationship between that type and the prototype.

Comment: Meaning it doesn't leave room for intermediate or successive types, which also have a relationship with a prototype (or several prototypes).

Comment: @colllin Yes, I suppose 1.0.1 is always lurking around the corner. Regarding your first comment, are you looking for a hypernym of _prototype_? (I ask because _animal_ is a hypernym of _mammal_.) Put another way, do you want a hierarchy of elements beginning with `prototype`, or would you prefer a chronology?

Comment: Thanks for turning me onto the concept of hypernyms and hyponyms. I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for. It's true that `animal` is a hypernym of `mammal`, but I think I'm looking for this: `An animal is a prototype of a mammal.`  `A mammal is a _____ of an animal.`

Comment: @colllin In what way is an animal a "prototype" of a mammal? Or are you using that word as a placeholder? I may not have understood the comment correctly.

Comment: After further thought, I think a better analogy would be Chair vs. Stool, from [Prototype Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory).  I will edit my question.

Answer (score 4):

While I like longstreth's *production unit*, you also might consider *[finished product](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finished-product)*

> the product that emerges at the end of a manufacturing process

SUPPLEMENT:

I think part of the problem is the term *[prototype](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/prototype?q=prototype)*.  This is often used in the sense of

> a first, typical or preliminary model of something, especially a machine, from which other forms are developed or copied

While it can also be understood as *archetype* it often conveys *preliminary*.

You may want to consider the term *[derivative](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/derivative?q=derivative)*

> something that is based on another source:
>   *a derivative of the system was chosen for the Marine Corps' V-22 tilt rotor aircraft*

It can be used as a noun on its own or as an adjective with *version, model* or other noun.  It is the term used in copyright law (which covers a good deal of programming) in the phrase *derivative work* which refers to a creative effort that is based in substantial part on a prior work.

In a more figurative vein, you could use the term *[daughter](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/daughter)*.

> •(literary) a thing personified as a daughter in relation to its origin or source:
>   Italian, the eldest daughter of ancient Latin
>
> •(Physics) a nuclide formed by the radioactive decay of another.

Continuing the familial theme, patent applications are often referred to as [*parent* and *daughter* applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=-gLuY2rBU9oC&pg=SA2-PA313&lpg=SA2-PA313&dq=patent%20parent%20daughter&source=bl&ots=qRfUz-6kFt&sig=_gLiMmlOz2LkdaqhSz-5eKLw9cQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KL_dUa7EDO66yAG_-IHgBQ&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=patent%20parent%20daughter&f=false), the latter following, being based on, and often refining the concepts contained in the former. The junior patents are also called *child* patents.

Comment: What if it's not the finished product?  Just a derivation, evolution, iteration, extension, (less primitive / more advanced / more defined) version, adaptation, or revision?

Answer (score 2):

**Derivative** can be used as a noun or as and adjective (as in "derivative design"). Another noun is **derivation**.

A *[derivative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derivative)* is something derived.

*[Derive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derive)* is to take, receive, or obtain, especially from a specified source; to have or take origin.

*[Derivation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derivation)* is something derived; or an act or process of deriving.

To modify your original statement

> This will not be true for versions that are based on this version.

you might say

> This will not be true for derivatives (of this version).

or

> This will not be true for derivative versions (of this design).

where the parenthetical can be left implicit if you like.

While it might sufficiently explained, let me provide some examples of it's direct and related uses:

[Derivative Design](http://www.makerbot.com/blog/2010/11/25/derivative-design-concept-open-source-disc-gun/) - new designs that are based upon existing designs, using design elements, concepts, or principles taken from those existing designs.

[Derivative Product](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/derivative-product.html):

> New product that results from modifying an existing product, and which has different properties than those of the product it is derived from.

Also, under [U.S. copyright law](http://www.legalzoom.com/intellectual-property-rights/copyrights/what-are-derivative-works-under):

> A derivative work is a new, original product that includes aspects of a preexisting, already copyrighted work.

As with many words, "derivative" has other meanings besides this one, but this should not be a limitation when used in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

How about "successor", or simply "future versions"?  The "that are based on this version" seems redundant; the object in question wouldn't be a "future version" of the prototype if it weren't based on the prototype.

Comment: True, but in the context of multiple product lines, for example, `future versions` by itself is a bit vague. Or in the context of the fact that you're reading it in a document, it could refer to versions of that document.

Comment: Maybe it was misleading to use the word `future`. In my particular use case, the time component is not really applicable. It's actually possible that the prototype is extracted from the derived version at a later time, and then other derivations of that prototype could occur. I'll try to find a better word and revise my question.  Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hmm... as far as I know there's no word that neatly fits as the counterpart of a prototype. You could clear things up by saying "future versions of ____", using "of" instead of "that are based on".

Answer (score 0):

'Beta version' could be a good term.

Comment: That's not the same kind of *prototype* this question is referring to. Read some of the examples.