# Name of application that works, but does not validate anything

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

This question is about programming (web development to be more specific).

I've been trying to find a word to describe a website that completely works from the frontend users perspective. But on the backend, nothing is actually being validated. So the application/website would be very easy for someone to screw around with (like deleting other users posts).

Best I've got at the moment is that it's "loosely built". But still requires a lot of explaining to make sense.

Has anyone heard of a expression/word for this? It doesn't have to be related to programming. You could also think of this as a building made out of paper mache, it might look solid and sturdy but it would very easily break.

Thanks!

Edit/Clarification:
Just to make it more clear. I mean that the website as mentioned above actually is intended to be complete and is currently a work in progress. Lets say this is a project for a client. He sees the website as 100% complete. But it might actually only be 20% complete (because nothing is validating on the backend, etc). So there is a lot more work to finish the project that it seems to be for outsiders.

Comment: vulnerable, proof of concept, glass house, demo, a shoddy imitation using pinball machine parts.

Comment: If people understand that it's not complete I'd call it a "prototype" or "test bed".

Answer (score 2):

A *mock-up* is a rough draft meant to give a sense of how the finished product will look or function.

---

From http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mock-up

> *1. A mock-up* is a rough draft meant to give a sense of how the finished product will look or function.
>
> - A model or replica of a machine or structure, used for instructional or experimental purposes.
>
> **Example sentences**
>
> - With full-size prototypes, mock-ups and models made with sample materials, tactility, texture, tone and technique are expressed.
> - This wasn't just any ordinary old white van either, according to the police, who said it was so unusual that it took time to provide a mock-up model for last week's crime reconstruction at the bank.
> - It has to be clear that the mock-up is for information purposes only, not to solicit comments for a redesign.
>
> 1.1 An arrangement of text and pictures to be printed:
>   More example sentences
>
> - A mock-up of the following day’s front page.
> - Management reviewed the text and mock-ups, but largely left the project to the author and designer.
> - In the next picture (a mock-up of the preferences screen) you've seen that I've put in an option to make that name editable or uneditable.
> - Last Saturday, a tabloid published a mock-up picture of him wearing a dunce's cap.

Comment: Please do not post images of text.  They are impossible to read for blind people, and impossible to search, copy and paste.  (Post text *as text*.)

Comment: Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Bare-bones** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bare+bones)

> *pl.n. Informal* The basic elements or essentials
>
> *"outlined the bare bones of the proposal"*

**Rudimentary** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rudimentary)

> not very developed or advanced

Or, if it's easily breakable

**House of cards** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+house+of+cards)

> an organization or a plan that is very weak and can easily be destroyed
>
> *"Their partners began to suspect that the company was a financial house of cards."*

Comment: I'm a programmer, too – "**rudimentary**" and "**unsecured**" (meaning "_we haven't tried yet_"; note that "insecure" could mean "_we tried and failed, or perhaps we have poor self-esteem, or both_" problems any which way) come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

A common term used by programmers for a preliminary version of a program
(for example, one that has much of the user interface roughed out
but very little of the functionality behind it — “under the hood”)
is ***prototype.***

> a first, typical or preliminary model of something,
>   especially a machine, from which other forms are developed or copied. 
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](https://www.google.com/#q=define+prototype)
>
> a rudimentary working model of a product or information system,
>   usually built for demonstration purposes or as part of the development process. 
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](http://searchmanufacturingerp.techtarget.com/definition/prototype)

There is a phrase ***thin client*** in computing:

> a client designed to be especially small
>   so that the bulk of the data processing occurs on the server. 
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/thin_client.html)
>
> A **thin client** is a lightweight computer
>   that is purpose-built for remoting into a server
>   (typically cloud or desktop virtualization environments). 
>   It depends heavily on another computer (its server)
>   to fulfill its computational roles. 
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client)

… all of which is a fancy way of saying that
a *thin client* doesn’t actually have much capability,
but it gives the illusion of having capability. 
Therefore, if you were to coin the phrase ***thin prototype,***
people might understand what you meant.

---

A more mundane term that might also work is ***façade:***

> a superficial appearance or illusion of something 
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/facade)
>
> a way of behaving or appearing
>   that gives other people a false idea of your true feelings or situation 
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facade)

---

See also: [What is the word for something that is based on a prototype?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/118923/26083)

Answer (score 0):

To name such *experimental* sites we usually use terms like: *surrogate* or *dummy*.

Comment: This would definitely fit. But in my case I don't mean it as a experimental website. It's more like a work in progress (that will in the end be complete, with validation and all the such). I'll clarify this is my question.

Comment: *Demo* or *Proof of Concept*?