# Alternative for "full-fledged"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I am looking for an alternative for "full-fledged".

> Mister X systematised its use and meaning, and developed the notion
>   into a **full-fledged** concept of ...

The context is academic, but not related to zoology. Its a paper about language and semantics, and I do not like the phrase "full-fledged" in those contexts, so I guess I have two questions:

1. Is this expression ok in this context
2. Notwithstanding Question #1, are there suitable alternatives?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. This is out of scope here: writing advice. If appropriate please recast the question in terms of what you would like explained about "full-fledged" and also present the research you did before asking here. Thanks.

Comment: @MετάEd: Do you post this comment to each and every question tagged as "word-choice"? I assume that behind most of these questions is somebody who sits at his desk and wants to write or express something, desperately looking for a better word. This is in part what this site is about: raising and answering questions about language and the use of language. The question I asked is a question I've been carrying around for a while. That I am currently writing a paper is only the immediate reason for asking it. but the question as such very well fits the scope of this site. I don't see your point.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58022 about this.

Comment: People can have all kinds of questions about using English; not all of them are appropriate for [english.se]. The FAQ excludes writing advice and general reference questions among other things. For writing advice consider [writers.se]. (We refer typography to [graphicdesign.se], learner's questions to [ell.se], etc.) Questions posed here need to be well researched and interesting to experts, and within the scope of this site as laid out in the [FAQ]. The owners of SE have explicitly discouraged word requests unless the question is especially interesting and well researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other [substitutes](http://thesaurus.com/browse/full-fledged) available for full-fledged can be :

> completely developed, developed, experienced, full-grown, grown,
>   grown-up, in full bloom, mature, qualified, schooled, seasoned,
>   skilled, trained, well-developed

In mine view mature will be more appropriate.

i.e.

> Mister X systematized its use and meaning, and developed the notion into a **mature** concept...

Comment: You can consider "fully developed" too.